# Amazon Alexa: Greet the user with the user's name in echo dot by asking the user's name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to make an app using Alexa using node js. I am new to these kind of things. I need to the following.

- Echo: Hi, I'm a Alexa. What's your name?
- User: Hi, I'm John Christopher
- Echo: Hello John Christopher, How can I help you?

Alexa should be able to capture the user's name and should be able to chat with the user by the his/her name. I have tried lots of things but I could't figure out a proper way to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon is developing the features more day by day. Currently, there is no direct method for getting the username prompted from the alexa device. But you can use AMAZON.NAMES for saving the names if the use nmae is in the name list and it can be saved in a session.

Answer (score 1):

The default skill project template that is created when you're using the ASK-CLI is a skill that does exactly that. Here is a link to video I did that will show you how to use the ASK-CLI to create a skill.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p-zlSdixCZ4